# Move specific items to the end of a list

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I have an `ArrayList` in `Java`:

```
{"deleteItem", "createitem", "exportitem", "deleteItems", "createItems"}
```

I want to move all string which contains `delete` to the end of the list, so I would get the next:

```
{"createitem", "exportitem", "createItems", "deleteItem", "deleteItems"}`
```

I can create two sublists - one for the words which contain the 'delete' word, and one for the others, and then merge them, but I search for a more efficient way.

Comment: Define "efficient"? Do you actually mean "elegant"? I have an inkling that performance is not important here, so perhaps maintainability is more important? If you really mean efficient, is space or time more important?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use custom Comparator:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
        "deleteItem", "createitem", "exportitem", "deleteItems", "createItems"
        );
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
        if (o1.contains("delete") && !o2.contains("delete")) {
            return 1;
        }else if (!o1.contains("delete") && o2.contains("delete")) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
Collections.sort(strings, comparator);
System.out.println(strings);
```

Comment: what if those `delete<>` strings should be sorted as well? i'm guessing since the author specified `deleteItem` before `deleteItems`

Comment: I guess you can just replace return 0; in method compare with return o1.compareTo(o2);

Answer (score 3):

If you want something efficient and need to remove elements in the beginning and middle of a `List` I would suggest using a `LinkedList` instead of a array list. That would avoid rewriting the underlying array for each remove operation.

Then, you simply iterate on the list, calling `remove` and `addLast` for any string that contains `delete`.

Of course, this is only OK if there is nothing preventing you from replacing your `ArrayList` with a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Ha, you are faster than me... :-)

Comment: Sometime you need luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You only want to put the elements with **delete** at the end of the list so ordering is O(nlogn) while we could do this in one pass, in O(n) (although using a new list). We could create a new LinkedLIst and pass through the original list adding the elements with "delete" at the end and the others at the begginging.

```
    LinkedList<String> orderedList = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String e:originalList){
        if (e.indexOf("delete")>=0) {
            orderedList.addLast(e);
        } else {
            orderedList.addFirst(e);
        }
    }
```

This is faster than sorting.

Comment: How is it efficient than solution provided by OP ?

Comment: Sorting, O(nlogn). We rely inthe sorting implementation of the JVM, is fairly good, we dont need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: But searching is O(n) and is his solution 2 searches and a join make is 3N but in Big Oh notation its O(n) correct me if i am wrong

Comment: True, and you only need one search. If you dont care of the order of anything else.